# Не работает ProgressDialog в потоке

Tags: android

У меня есть `Fragment` и `Handler`. В `onCreateView` я пытаюсь записать в базу 10 000 записей, показывая при этом прогресс в `ProgressDialog`:

```
class CreatePageFragment extends Fragment {

    ...
    ...
    ...

    private class ProgressHandler extends Handler {
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        private int maxProgress;
        private Context mContext;

        ProgressHandler(Context c, int max) {
            mContext = c;
            maxProgress = max;

            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Загрузка");
            progressDialog.setMessage("Идет загрузка...");
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            progressDialog.setMax(maxProgress);
        }

        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (progressDialog.getProgress() < progressDialog.getMax()) {
                progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(1);

                if (progressDialog.getProgress() == progressDialog.getMax()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            } else {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        public void start() {
            progressDialog.show();
        }
    }

    ...
    ...
    ...

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_table, container, false);

        final ProgressHandler handler = new ProgressHandler(getActivity(), 10000);
        handler.start();

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    DataBase dataBase = new DataBase(getActivity(), myBase);
                    SQLiteDatabase db = dataBase.getWritableDatabase();

                    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

                    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {

                        cv.put("column_1", 1);
                        cv.put("column_2", "text");
                        cv.put("column_3", "text");

                        db.insert("my_table", null, cv);

                        cv.clear();

                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

                    }

                    db.close();
                    dataBase.close();

                }
            });

        thread.start();

        //Ожидание окончания загрузки
        synchronized (this) {
            try {
                thread.join();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

        return view;
    }

    ...
    ...
    ...

}
```

Проблема в том, что у меня появляется просто черный экран и запись идет без диалога, хотя цикл работает (проверял в логах). Почему не появляется диалог?

Comment: ну так а что Вы хотите увидеть? если Вы стопорите `onCreateView`, `UI` не отобразится пока `onCreateView` не отработает

Comment: @bukashka101. Никогда не выполняйте запись большого количества данных в базу "просто в другом потоке". Может случиться так, что процесс прервётся на половине действия. Тут долго объяснять такие случаи, просто погуглите на тему "Почему AsyncTask устарел". Знаю, что AsyncTask у вас тут не используется, но смысл вы поймёте.

Comment: @BORSHEVIK, почитал. Тогда что использовать для трудоемких задач?

Comment: @bukashka101 Дело в том, что AsyncTask тоже можно юзать, но только в тех случаях, когда окончание работы потока не важно, как пример - это ситуации, когда вы подгружаете картинки из интернета для вывода на экран, т.е. если они не загрузятся, то и фиг с ним, а вот в ситуациях с вашей дело куда серьёзнее, т.к. если что-то в БД не ляжет, то потом могу возникнуть траблы. Можете использовать IntentService, он 100% гарантирует вам выполнение работы потока.

Comment: @BORSHEVIK, тогда толку от `AsyncTask`, если короткие задачи и основной поток сможет выполнить.

Comment: @bukashka101 Мочь то может, а паттерны ещё никто не отменял. Ведь согласитесь, намного удобнее видеть в основном коде всего две строки (Объявление таска и запуск), а всё остальное вынести за пределы класса, в кукую-нибудь другую папку, нежели городить гаргары в коде, которые будут потом вам мешать ориентироваться. Есть ещё такая штука как **Loader**, почитайте, просто классная штукенция, а люди ей боятся пользоваться, хотя она тоже работает в другом потоке и казалось бы нафиг она нужна, если есть Thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю ваша проблема в вызове метода Join() в строке `thread.join();`. Он заставляет основной поток дожидаться выполнения работы потока, поэтому View ещё не подготовлена и вы видите чёрный экран