# Как загрузить данные из БД, показывая процесс ProgressDialog'ом

Tags: android

Мне нужно загрузить данные из базы данных в `ArrayList`, вo втором потоке, сопровождая выгрузку `DialogFragment'ом`. При помощи чего это можно сделать?

---

Хотел сделать через `IntentServise`, но он не дружит с `List'ами` (насколько я понял). Проповал запустить выгрузку во втором потоке, остановивши первый, но `ProgressDialog` спит с основным потоком. Даже пробовал сделать все в основном потоке, но `ProgressDialog` не успевает запуститься и зависает с основным потоком...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делается это через `AsyncTask`, примерная схема такая:

1. Создаем класс наследующий от `AsyncTask`
2. В конструкторе класса создаем `ProgressDialog`
3. В методе `onPreExecute()` показываем диалог `progressDialog.show()`, проводим другие мероприятия - подготовку у чтению БД и проч.
4. В методе `doInBackground()` организуем чтение данных из БД в цикле и в ходе чтения вызываем `this.publishProgress()`, который будет вызывать `onProgressUpdate()` (см. ниже)
5. В методе `onProgressUpdate()` увеличиваем счетчик `progressDialog.setProgress()`
6. В методе `onPostExecute()` закрываем счетчик `progressDialog.dismiss()`

Comment: А `AsyncTask` не создаст проблем? Он же ненадежный в работе с долгими операциями.

Comment: Кто сказал такую ересь?

Comment: Тут -http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/469382/Не-работает-progressdialog-в-потоке?noredirect=1#comment523764_469382 и в гугле.

Comment: @bukashka101 вы либо слушайте советы старых бойцов либо дальше гуглите. Описанный мной алгоритм это не теоретические измышления - а взят из моего собственного кода, который нормально абсолютно работает на апргейде БД из 10 тыс. записей

Comment: сегодня добой доберусь и попробую. Правда потупить над поворотом экрана придется (хорошо что на startandroi'e есть по этому урок).

Comment: Я создал ОЧЕНЬ упрощенную версию `AsyncTask'a`, как Вы сказали, но он отказывается работать уже на `.show()`. Сначала весь `AsyncTask` выполняется, а уже потом открывается активность (может даже и сам `ProgressBar`, но я так и не дождался конца загрузки :)). Можете помочь — http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/470182/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-progressdialog-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-asynctask/470222#470222 ?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте сделать через `AsyncTask`, у него есть методы `onPreExecute` и `onPostExecute`, которые выполняются соответственно, перед и после `doInBackground` на UI потоке (точнее на потоке, который вызвал `execute()` у `AsyncTask`). Показывайте и прячте ваш `DialogFragment` в этих методах, а загрузку из базы сделайте в `doInBackground`