# Как показать ProgressDialog при выполнении AsyncTask

Tags: android

У меня есть класс, наследующий `AsyncTask`:

```
class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {
    private Context mContext;
    private String baseName;

    private DataBase dataBase;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    LoadData(Context context, String name) {
        mContext = context;
        baseName = name;

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Загрузка");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Идет загрузка...");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            dataBase = new DataBase(mContext, baseName);
            db = dataBase.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

            cv.put("text_1", "text 1");
            cv.put("text_2", "text 2");
            cv.put("text_3", "text 3");
            cv.put("text_4", "text 4");
            cv.put("text_5", "text 5");

            db.insert("text", null, cv);

            db.close();
            dataBase.close();
        }

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

В `activity` я его вызываю и жду завершения так (после вызова `setContentView`):

```
LoadData loadData = new LoadData(this, "myBase");
loadData.execute();

try {
    int num = loadData.get();
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

Проблема в том, что диалог не появляется. Просто черный экран, но в логе видно, что поток работает!

Как заставить этот диалог появится, а активность ждать его завершения?

Comment: Зачем нужно выводить операцию в отдельный поток, чтобы потом тормозить основной поток, дожидаясь выполнения отдельного потока? Смысл отдельного потока в том, что основной поток не должен ЖДАТЬ его завершения.

Comment: @pavlofff, а я был готов к этому вопросу! :D Чтобы, при повороте экрана, восстановиться `AsyncTask` со всеми загруженными данными. Если он заполнен на половину — восстановится на половину, заполнен полностью — восстановлю полностью и сразу получу результат. А как в `Activity` это сделать я не знаю. Да и пробовал я сделать то же в активности, но она зависала и ее иалог даже не успевал появляться.

Comment: Переопределять методы работы с UI-потоком внутри самого `AsyncTask` бессмысленно - он не имеет доступа к UI и соответственно ничего отображаться не будет, как вы сами уже заметили. Таким образом вы в очередной раз придумываете самодельный костыль и задаете по нему вопросы, вместо того, чтобы решать действительную проблему - как сохранять состояние асинктаска при повороте активити.

Comment: @pavlofff, как сохранить состояние `AsyncTask'a`, при повороте экрана я уже понял, а вот как заставить его показывать диалог... Сейчас пойду попробую вариант @Saidolim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создаете `ProgressDialog` в `Activity` а из `AsyncTask` меняете его параметры.

В `LoadData` создайте конструктор и передайте активити. типо

```
private MyActivity myActivity;
public LoadData (MyActivity myActivity){
    this.myActivity = myActivity;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    this.myActivity.progressDialogShow(true);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    this.myActivity.progressDialogShow(false);
}
```

идея типо этого.

А в `Activity` нужна функция

```
public void progressDialogShow(boolean isShow){
    // Если isShow = true нужно показать ProgressBar
    // else Отключит его
}
```

также можно показыват % значения при работе через функцию

```
onProgressUpdate(Progress...)
```

**UPD:**
*из комментов*

Вызов `get` в основной `activity` создает черный экран, так как ожидает полного завершения `AsyncTask`.

**UPD2:**

После обшений в комментария, обновил ответ

Comment: Результат тот же...

Comment: @bukashka101, этот ответ полностью правилен. Надо тольео упомянуть, что вызовом `.get();` над таском вы начинаете ждать его исполнения в основном потоке. Что полностью убивает с предельной жестокостью сам смысл существования таксов как таковых.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я уже писал pavlofff, зачем я так сделал. Комментарии под вопросом.

Comment: @bukashka101, я ничего не понял. Вы хотите востановить прогресс в диалогах при повороте активити?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, если перевернут экран — да. И не только прогресс, а еще и полученные данные, которые будут в переменных (диалог который тут, только "пробная" версия, потом я буду еще и закачку данных из БД делать).

Comment: @bukashka101, ну... Вы же, небось, знаете, как сохранять/восстанавливать данные при повороте активити... Вот и восстановите...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, знаю. Но есть еще одна вторая проблема, которую я хотел решить через `AsyncTask` — активность не успевает вызвать диалог, начинается загрузка и все зависает. К сожалению, с `AsyncTask` такая же проблема. И если я вызову загрузку 10 000 полей в основной активности, она зависнет вместе с диалогом.

Comment: @bukashka101, повторюсь - зависание из-за `get()`;

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, это я уже понял. Но почему `ProgressDialog` не вызывается? Его вызов же идет до вызова `.get()`!

Comment: @bukashka101, ну, видать асинхронность там какая-то... Может onPreExecute() вызывается после get() или show() после гет. Прологгируйте и посмотрите. С исходниках покопайтесь. Но зачем вам вообще это знать? Не используйте гет и вам не придётся вообще об этом думать.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, ну допустим, что асинхронность в `AsyncTask` и все не работает из-за него, но `setContenyView()` я ТОЧНО вызываю вообще до создания `AsyncTask`, но `AsyncTask` запускается, работает, а экран черный! Почему? Кстати, отвлекся от компьютера, сходил на тренировку и, во время спаринга :)), до меня дошло, что, в самом конце `doInBackground` нужно вызвать метод из активности, который все остальное сделает. Тогда и `get()` не нужен. Осталось понять почему не работает `setContentView`, вдруг пригодится.

Comment: @bukashka101, экран чёрный скорее вего из-за того, что вы поток замораживаете гетом в онкреэйте. Вот он не успевает завершиться и экран не отрисовывает. Думаю, если вы гет в onResume вызовете, то экран чёрным не будет, т.к. отрисоваться успеет.

Comment: @bukashka101 вы `setContentView` где вызываете? в `doInBackground`  или в `onPostExecute`. нужно в `onPostExecute`. И все функции вашего `Activity` доступны через переменную `private MyActivity myActivity;`

Comment: @Saidolimm в `onCreate` я вызываю. В самой активности. А уже потом создаю `AsyncTask`. И добавьте в ответ, что `get` создает черный экран.

Comment: Нарушаете [Закон Деметры](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Закон_Деметры) Даже в качестве примера на коленке не стоит так делать.

Comment: Если AsyncTask предназначень только для этого активити (у меня пример оттуда и идет) тогда Закон Деметры не нарушается, так как 2й пункт закона - должен взаимодействовать только с известными ему модулями «друзьями», не взаимодействовать с незнакомцами.- так как этот AsyncTask полностью друг самого Activity. Конечно можно было создать отдельную функцию управления Dialog в самом Activity и его использовать, но будет сложнее объяснить самое главное, ответ на вопрос.

Comment: Вы не правы. Завтра progressdialog заменят на progressbar и вам придется менять два класса. И/или создадут dialogfragment и получите проблемы с жизненным циклом фрагментов... В итоге все это превращается в `try{..}catch(Exception e){}`, как в коде из вопроса.

Comment: @YuraIvanov согласень. вы правы. но это же как пример. или думаете мне лучше его изменить?

Comment: Ваш пример правильно реализуется созданием интерфейса, который имплементит activity, LoadData вызывает методы интерфейса (приводя контекст, переданный в конструктор, к типу интерфейса). То же самое касается передачи результата работы AsyncTask'а - собственно решение проблемы `.get()`. //Аналогичный паттерн описан в документации по поводу общения фрагментов и activity, когда фрагмент не должен ничего знать об активити, кроме как о данных методах, описанных в интерфейсе.

Comment: Спасибо всем, обновил ответ. Думаю теперь лучше.